# How to view multiple relationships in contact editing mode?

Tags: contacts, relationships

If a contact is an employee of multiple organizations at the same time, is there an option to Add New Relationship in the contact editing mode so that multiple relationships can be shown in the editing mode as well, and not only when looking at the Relationships Tab?

Comment: I am using the CiviCRM version 4.6.12. by the way, WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Sorry!